# How to I get GMT standard time when setting up schedule in Azure using DevOps

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, runbook

I have a runbook that I run in DevOps to set up a schedule in Azure using `Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook`

I cannot seem to get it to set to UK time. The VM is in Western Europe.

However when I use:

`TimeZone              =  "GMT Standard Time"`

The times I put for my schedule get an hour added onto them.

Does anyone know how to get the schedule to set to UK time please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The United Kingdom uses Greenwich Mean Time or **Western European Time** (UTC) and British Summer Time or Western European Summer Time (UTC+01:00).

To change the current time zone from PowerShell, run the command

```
$TimeZone = "W. Europe Standard Time"
New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName krishtoautomationdemo -Name "MySchedule" -StartTime "23:00" -OneTime -ResourceGroupName HariMT -TimeZone $TimeZone
```

Where $TimeZone variable contains the Id of the TimeZone.

**Output:**

[image]

***Note:***
In the Local or Azure PowerShell, Run this command to get Ids of each time zone.

```
Get-TimeZone -ListAvailable
```

That Id is used to set timezone for creating the resources in Cloud through PowerShell.
[image]

UK is the country in Europe so it uses GMT or W. Europe time (UTC +01:00).

Comment: Great 0 thank you. And will this take account for the British daylight savings changes when the happen?

Comment: Hi @abinitio, the script what i have mentioned, that will even effect the daylight saving changes as well

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT  - this doesn't seem to work. When I use W. European Time in my pipeline it comes up as  "Central European Time" and seems to have two hours added to the time I input. Which I find very confusing.

Comment: Hi @abinitio, W. European Time and Central European Time has different Ids and [time gap](https://i.imgur.com/MLdVFXT.png). Central Eu. Time has 1 hour ahead than the W. European Time and 2 hours ahead than the GMT.
Please check once the Id you used in the Timezone.

Comment: @abinitio, try checking the id you provided once and if still getting the same, could you provide me any screenshot